# POST data using POSTMAN: ASP.Net

Tags: c#

I have created a simple API for city data using an ASP.NET API. I want to POST data using Postman. I have a controller set up to create an Id, Name, and Description. The problem I'm having is that after submitting the data, I am creating a new 'pointofinterest' with Null values for Name and Description.

1. I have Content-Type set to 'application/json' with no addition header values set.

   2. Getting Data works perfectly fine.

What's the problem?

[Link: Postman Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/732OL.png)

Controller

```
 [HttpPost("{cityId}/pointsofinterest")]
        public IActionResult CreatePointOfInterest(int cityId,
            [FromBody]PointOfInterestForCreationDto pointOfInterest)
        {
            if (pointOfInterest == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var city = CitiesDataStore.Current.Cities.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == cityId); 

            if (city == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var maxPointOfInterestId = CitiesDataStore.Current.Cities.SelectMany(
                c => c.PointsOfInterest).Max(p => p.Id);

            var finalPointOfInterest = new PointOfInterestDto()
            {
                Id = ++maxPointOfInterestId,
                Name = pointOfInterest.Name,
                Description = pointOfInterest.Description
            };

            city.PointsOfInterest.Add(finalPointOfInterest);

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetPointOfInterest", new { cityId = cityId, id = finalPointOfInterest.Id}, finalPointOfInterest);
        }
```

PointOfInterestForCreationDto

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CityInfo.API.Models
{
    public class PointOfInterestForCreationDto
    {
        //[Required(ErrorMessage ="I need your name.")]
        //[MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //[MaxLength(200)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[Link: Postman Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/732OL.png)

Comment: Can you post your PointOfInterestForCreationDto model and also your postman screen.

Comment: Sure. Just did.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "name" to "**Name**" and "description" to "**Description**" in the body of Postman.

```
{    
    "Name" : "Pere Lachaise",
    "Description" : "Famous cemetery where Jim Morrison and Oscar Wilde are buried"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it ? Do you get the Name and Description in "pointOfInterest" object ? @FIVEMANGO

Comment: I do not receive values for Name and Description, but I do pass my tests...

Comment: If you do not have the values, it means there is issue with your http request. Somehow the body of the http request does not contain the values to be posted

Answer (score -1):

Solution: I deleted all extra files inside of my solution.

Comment: How is this a solution to anything?

Comment: One of my files was misdirecting the flow of my API. It's probably rare.